# How get posts from a subcategory of a category by name?

Tags: wp-query, categories

I'm trying to create a subcategory template of a defined category. 
For example, for each one, I would like to check if his subcategory `Photos` exists and to get posts of this.

Here is my category tree:

```
— Category Sessions
— — Subcategory Session 2015
— — — Subcategory Photos
— — — Subcategory ...
— — — Subcategory Videos
— — Subcategory Session 2014
— — — Subcategory Photos
— — — Subcategory ...
— — — Subcategory Videos
— — Subcategory Session 2013
— — — Subcategory Photos
— — — Subcategory ...
— — — Subcategory Videos
```

If subcategory `Photos` of **this** session category exists :

My idea is to have a query such as :

`$wp_query = new WP_query(... Session 20XX/Photos ...&showposts=20);`

Is there a way to do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Getting Parent ID
$parent = get_term_by( 'name', 'Session 2015', 'category');

// Checking if SubCategory Exist. 
$term = term_exists('Photos', 'category', $parent->term_id);

//if Exist Do the query
if ($term !== 0 && $term !== null) {
  $query = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$term['term_id'] );
}
```

References:

- [`term_exists`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)
- [`get_term_by`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

Comment: @M Haseeb Wooow! Thank you, it seems good. I'll try that.

Comment: BIM! Huge! Thank you so muck Haseeb. Exactly what I want.